# How to name columns in dataframes using a string in Julia?

Tags: string, dataframe, julia

I am trying to find a way to name columns of a dataframe using strings coming from excel or scraping the web.

So how to transform "colname" to colname below?

```
df = DataFrame(colname = [1, 2])
```

I tried

```
df = DataFrame(symbol("colname") = [1, 2])
```

or

```
df = DataFrame([1, 2], [symbol("colname")])
```

and many other combinations, but no success.
I see questions related to deleting columns based on string column names but no question/answer for naming columns in the first place.

Comment: You could use this signature `DataFrame(columns::Vector{Any},names::Vector{Symbol})` to build up your data frame.

Comment: Would you mind giving a working example besides the formal definition?

Comment: If I try something simple: `DataFrame([1], [symbol("colname")])` I get `DataFrame has no method matching DataFrame(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Symbol,1})
while loading In[589], in expression starting on line 1` while there is indeed a constructor `DataFrame(columns::Array{Any,1},cnames::Array{Symbol,1})` what you may be referring to, @jverzani.

Comment: `[`1]` is not of type `Vector{Any}`. Try: `Any[[1]]` (An `Any` vector of vector(s) with length to match the symbols vector.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May be you can try something like this in two steps using the `names!` function.

```
using DataFrames
newname = ["colname1", "colname2"]
df = DataFrame(v1 = [1, 2], v2 = [3, 4])
names!(df.colindex, map(parse, newname))
df
# 2x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
# | Row | colname1 | colname2 |
# |-----|----------|----------|
# | 1   | 1        | 3        |
# | 2   | 2        | 4        |
```

Here are the version of `Julia` and `DataFrames.jl` I used

```
versioninfo()
# Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+6991
# Commit 811a977 (2015-08-26 04:02 UTC)
# Platform Info:
#   System: Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
#   CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
#   WORD_SIZE: 64
#   BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
#   LAPACK: libopenblas
#   LIBM: libopenlibm
#   LLVM: libLLVM-svn


Pkg.installed("DataFrames")
# v"0.6.9"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the column name string has a space in it? Throws an error currently.

Comment: @DavidZentler-Munro You are right, I will update my answer. You can use `names!(df.colindex, map(Symbol, newname))` it should work